# Declaring and initializing ints, error when calling constructor

Tags: java, int

When I try to create new int object:

```
int g= new int();
```

netbeans tells me:

```
Incompatible types
required: int
found: int[]
'[' expected
illegal start of expresion.
```

I want to simply create new int.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

For primitive datatypes you dont have a constructor:

```
int g = 5;
```

or just say

```
int g; //declaration
```

But keep in mind, there are also Classes which contain more functionallity for every primitive Datatype. Its the Datatypes name written with the first letter upper case:

```
Integer g = new Integer(5); //but it needs the parameter
```

Where you for example have a function to create an Integer out of a String:

```
Integer.parseInt("5");
```

But there is not really much need for them for the declaration part.

Answer (score 4):

There are no constructors for primitives since they are not objects.  They are simply declared and initialized like so:

```
int x = num;
```

If you want/need to use an object, you can use the wrapper [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html):

```
Integer x = new Integer(num);
```

Consider the following example on [auto-unboxing and unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html):

```
int x_unboxed = new Integer(num); // unboxing

Integer x_boxed = 5;  // autoboxing
```

**Unboxing** is going from `Integer` or `Wrapper` to `int` or `primitive`.
**Autoboxing** is going from `int` or `primitive` to `Integer` or `Wrapper`.

Basically a `Wrapper` is an immutable object that *wraps* around a `primitive`.  In this case, `Integer` contains a `private final int`.

You may need to use a wrapper, if for example, you wanted to use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), which cannot hold primitives.

Comment: I believe the right answer is indeed to highlight the differences between primitives and objects. Maybe you could expand your answer with a relation between primitive types and related objects and perhaps even mention auto-boxing?

Comment: I saw, thank you. I believe that is all needed to work with primitives when new to Java! ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of ints in Java.

**Primitives**

```
int g = 1;
```

**Objects**

```
Integer gObject = new Integer(1);
```

There is also an important thing in Java called **autoboxing**. It's an implicit conversion between primitives and objects.

**Autoboxing**

```
gObject = g; // equivalent to Integer.valueOf(g)
g = gObject; // equivalent to gObject.intValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to 'new' a class or an array in order to create a specific instance of the class /array. 'int' is a primitive data type so you can simply use it directly:

```
int g;

g = 10;

System.out.println("g is: " + g);
```

You'll want to consult some introductory Java tutorials or books and work through the basic data types and learn about classes/objects in more detail.

If instead you wanted to create an array of ten integers, you'd have

```
int[] g = new int[10];
```

which is why you're getting the perplexing error message you see.

Good luck!

Comment: The funny thing is that i'm curently "Reading Thinking in Java" And something about classes and objects and that basic types are special in some kind, but i didn't know that they don't need a contstructor. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an integer object by typing

```
    int g=new int()
```

This is wrong in Java, as you cannot create objects out of primitive types. Java is 99% object oriented language. Since it does not get rid of primitive types such as int, float etc., you cannot call is purely object oriented.

What you can do is simply:

```
    int g;
    Integer g1=new Integer(g);
```

That would satisfy your need of an integer object. Integer is a wrapper class that wraps the int g, and create an object out of it.
Remember, you can use **new** only when you are creating an object of a class, and Integer is a class, int is not a class.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

That's an unfortunate design decision in Java that primitive types (`int` is one of them) are treated differently from objects. You cannot use `new` to create an `int`; you treat them just like you would in C, for example – just assign a value, no need to construct anything:

```
int foo = 0;
```

Note that you cannot use local variables that haven't been initialised explicitly before.

There are wrapper classes, e.g. `Integer` that simply wrap primitive types to allow them to be used in contexts where an actual object or class is required (e.g. generics), but in your case that doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: You could use the classes I guess. `Integer g = new Integer();`

Comment: While it is your opinion that it is an "unfortunate" design decision, I'd advise to keep answers to very basic Java questions free of opinions.

Comment: Is that what the downvote is for? And it *is* unfortunate. It bites developers left and right, it hampers performance (because of constant boxing and unboxing) and in the end, especially with JIT compilers getting better, was not worth the trouble. It cannot be changed now either, of course, but that doesn't mean it wasn't a mistake in hindsight. A tradeoff that turned out to be not the best idea.

Comment: Yes, I believe that opinions are not useful to someone who needs to get a hold of the basics. These should be given as unbiased as possible.